# How much space do i need for ubuntu dualboot?

Tags: dual-boot, java, eclipse, intellij

I'm using windows 8.1 and i want to learn linux and also want to use it for **java** and **clojure** development. I'm gonna use IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse. How much space i need to save on my localdisc for ubuntu for normal work. Im totally new to linux so i don't know how much disc space 
you need when you want to develop java application on ubuntu os?

Comment: Can you give us more details why you need to know the exact amount? It will really depend how much source you will need to handle. Also both IDEs will need to create index-files. Will you need git or svn?

Comment: Sorry i'm student and beginner so i'm not sure if i will switch to Ubuntu full time so i want to play with it to see if i like it. Yes i am using git. I'm thinking to slice my drive and leave some space (maybe ~60gb) for Ubuntu, IDEs, index-files and everything else whats necessary for development. Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually recommend at least 50GB for Ubuntu, but since you are using this for development, you have a few options. If you plan to use the same files in both OS', then you can simply mount the NTSF partition and use the same files for both systems. For users seriously considering switching to Ubuntu full time, I recommend slicing their drive in half. The frustrating/awesome thing about Linux is that it's your choice.